# How to maintain cursor position when enforcing Change() on a UserForm TextBox?

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform, uppercase

Suppose I have this following code in my EXCEL VBA UserForm:

```
Private Sub TextBox_Change()

TextBox.Value = UCase(TextBox.Value)

OtherText.Value = "FOO " & TextBox.value & " BAR"

End Sub
```

It forces the textbox to be always upper case, and works well *when users type from the end*.

However say I was given a text `"HELLO WORLD"` and I wanted to *insert* `"CRUEL "` in between (typed manually by users), as soon as I type in `C`, the cursor would jump to after `D` and the end result would become `"HELLO CWORLDRUEL "` (if I typed blindly).

The cursor position wouldn't change if I had caps lock on, but it defeats the purpose of the code... and with a lower case character it always kicks the cursor to the end.

**Is there a way to maintain the cursor position for these type of forced-case changes?**

I had considered using `_Exit()` method but I do want to keep both the `OtherText` and `TextBox` value uppercase with each change.  Otherwise `OtherText` would be all uppercase, while `TextBox` is still lowercase before the `_Exit()` is executed and it looks... undesirable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a different event, such as the following:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If KeyAscii >= 97 And KeyAscii <= 122 Then 'a-z
      KeyAscii = Asc(UCase(Chr(KeyAscii)))
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the cursor position using `SelStart`, then reset the cursor when you're done manipulating the text.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim cursorPos As Long
    cursorPos = Me.TextBox1.SelStart
    Me.TextBox1.Text = UCase(Me.TextBox1.Text)
    Me.TextBox1.SelStart = cursorPos
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Also a nice implementation but I felt the `KeyPress` was a bit more readable to me, and I don't have to use another variable :)  Thank you though! +1

Comment: @MathieuGuindon good advice.  I understand explicit is better than implicit, but I'll confess I'm not a programming expert so a lot of these "philosophies" whooshes me by without others' expertise.  I'll take your comment to heart and consider these caveats in the future.

Comment: @Idlehands nah, that's what I get for reading the answers before the question - ignore my previous comment (deleted), Brian's approach is flawless. The problem with the caret position was caused by the handler rewriting the textbox' contents, and this code has the same issue: correcting the caret position is indeed done like this (upvoted), but it shouldn't need to be done in the first place.

Comment: I also agree that Brian's approach is cleaner than mine (take your upvote!). I'll have to consider re-factoring some of my code if this situation comes up again. Correcting the cursor position was a solution I came up with when handling a situation that called for a numeric value in a text box that I wanted kept in a '0.00' format. In this situation, I am rewriting the textbox contents to keep the decimal place, but I have to account for cursor movements and insertions. It's a somewhat different situation that OP's above.